# Regression for non-normal distributions

Tags: regression, data-visualization, python, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

Firstly I apologize for being very green in statistics. I'm trying to plot a regression for what I believe to be a couple of non-normal distributions.

I have done some reading and I think that the distributions are possibly Poisson distributions but perhaps they are negative binomial distributions?

These are both count data which led me to the belief that they are Poisson distributions. Aside: Clearly they are some outliers for the "Days Off Work" dataset.

Any assistance is much appreciated. Below is what I tried which doesn't seem to me to be helpful. Perhaps I'm wrong about that, though.

If indeed I need to perform a different type of regression on these data I would very much appreciate assistance in doing so in Python hence the tag.

[image]

Without the extreme outliers on the x-axis:

[image]

Comment: The variable on your y-axis might be Poisson or negative binomial but the one on the x-axis looks more like a mixture of two distributions, one for the  common values and one for the very long stays off work

Comment: Thank you for your comment @mdewey. I can remove the outliers on the x-axis...

Comment: They may be the most interesting observations of course.

Comment: That is possible, @mdewey, though I am ok with dealing with them apart from the regression if that makes any sense. I have added a plot without them.